# Genetic algorithms in python, is there a maximum amounts of data or maximum number of parameters?

Tags: python, python-2.7, csv, if-statement, append

I am making a construct to run my first genetic/evolutionary algorithm in python. Is there a maximum amount of data that can be handled by such algorithms or a maximum number of parameters that can be taken into account?

Furthermore, how much does the computational power of the computer used for such an algorithm matter? I have a model to solve with over 5GB of data, and containing 250+ numeric parameters.

I know such non coding vague questions seem to be taboo on Stackoverflow, but this is the most comprehensive python knowledge pool on the internet.

Any wisdom or advice in this sphere would be greatly appreciated.

Many thanks GTPE

Answer (score 4):

The limit is "when you run out of memory" usually you will run out of patience first - BUT you can always find other approaches, e.g. create a class to store your parameters and pass that as a single parameter, structure your processing so that it is working on part of your data at any one time - these two are very good starts for being able to share the load off to other cores and/or machines which resolves the power problem.

Comment: Thank you very much for giving an answer! I have previously run evolutionary algorithms in excel (v slow) but that was for much less data. I used to run these sometimes for days at a time. Is this sort of time frame expected using python, my 250 parameters are the results of 250 different variable polynomial regressions

Comment: Python is very class based - but if your can take the approach above you will be able to use multiprocess to use all your cores or pyro to use all the machines on your network - with the users permission of course.  You will find that python is much faster than excel if you structure your problem.

Comment: Comments and advise like this is invaluable! Do you have any recommended reading on genetic algorithms?